# How to add a runtime field to index pattern that converts string to date?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index that contains a "createdAt" string field I would like to convert to date.

I'm trying to that via the UI and since scripted fields are [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-index-patterns.html#scripted-fields) I understand I should use [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-index-patterns.html#create-runtime-fields).

I've figuired out to convert a string to date object and while it works for actual runtime queries, If i set a field using Index Pattern settings, the values don't seem to be shown on Kibana.

Here's how I setup the field:

[image: Image showing how the dateobject field is set]

And while the same code works, if I try to visualize the data in Kibana I see "no results found".

[image: Image showing the Kibana is empty]

I don't understand where the issue is as the following query presents the field just fine:

```
GET mails/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "exampleColumn": {
      "type": "date",
      "script": {
        "source":
        """emit(new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss').parse(doc['createdAt.keyword'].value).getTime())"""
      }
    }
  },
  "fields" : ["exampleColumn"]
}
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?
Any help will be appritiated.

Comment: Maybe dumb question, but does the kibana time filter indicate and is it filtering on a different time field?

Comment: @BenjaminTrent If I understood correctly, you're taking about the time filter in the top right corner? I don't see that it goes by any specific field

Comment: It goes by the timefield set in the index pattern. This is set in the [index pattern settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html).